# Reducing horizontal space in math mode align

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The following code aligns everything just the way I want -- and I can be much too picky -- except that the horizontal space to the last column is too wide. How can I make it narrower?

```
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 2 &  -3 & 1 \\
        2 & 5 &  -8 & 4
    \end{pmatrix*}
    &\sim
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 2 &  -3 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 &  -2 &  2
    \end{pmatrix*}
    && %\qquad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\
        \leftarrow -2r_1 + r_2 
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &\sim
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
        0 & 1 &  -2 &  2
    \end{pmatrix*}
    && %\qquad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \leftarrow -2r_2 + r_1 \\
        \\
    \end{matrix*}
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\begin{alignat*}{3} ... \end{alignat*}` and replace the `&& %\qquad` with `& \quad`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}% <-- includes amsmath

\begin{document}
Using \verb|align*|
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 2 &  -3 & 1 \\
        2 & 5 &  -8 & 4
    \end{pmatrix*}
    &\sim
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 2 &  -3 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 &  -2 &  2
    \end{pmatrix*}
    && %\qquad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\
        \leftarrow -2r_1 + r_2 
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &\sim
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
        0 & 1 &  -2 &  2
    \end{pmatrix*}
    && %\qquad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \leftarrow -2r_2 + r_1 \\
        \\
    \end{matrix*}
\end{align*}
Using \verb|alignat*|
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 2 &  -3 & 1 \\
        2 & 5 &  -8 & 4
    \end{pmatrix*}
    &\sim
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 2 &  -3 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 &  -2 &  2
    \end{pmatrix*}
    & \quad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\
        \leftarrow -2r_1 + r_2 
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &\sim
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
        0 & 1 &  -2 &  2
    \end{pmatrix*}
    & \quad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \leftarrow -2r_2 + r_1 \\
        \\
    \end{matrix*}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`aligned` allows several alignment points using the `&` symbol. If you need more space for the last column, use `qquad` or a similar `hspace`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 2 &  -3 & 1 \\
        2 & 5 &  -8 & 4
    \end{pmatrix*}
    &\sim
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 2 &  -3 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 &  -2 &  2
    \end{pmatrix*}
    & \leftarrow -2r_1 + r_2 \\
    &\sim
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
        0 & 1 &  -2 &  2
    \end{pmatrix*}
    & \leftarrow -2r_2 + r_1 
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]